# How to do ssh tunneling in Windows

Tags: windows, ssh-tunnel

I'm using windows 7 and I want to redirect one of the ports on localhost to IP which is accessible from another jump host.
Is there any tool to do that, 
I want to achieve following--
localhost:5000->windows_server(with credentials)->local ip for windows server

Comment: You can do that with PuTTY.

Comment: how? can you provide some example, the jump host is windows server

Answer (score -1):

I would personally recommend looking into the the free, open source **STunnel**, to see if it suits your requirements.

https://www.stunnel.org/index.html

This can be run via the command line, its own GUI, and as a Windows Service that can automatically start at boot time.

Stunnel can act as a tunnel for clients from you local machine to a remote server (and optionally provide a tunnel to clients to connect to endpoints on your local machine).

The basic principal is that you edit a configuration file to provide mapping of a local port to a remote host and port combination.

There are comprehensive examples included in the default configuration file; the Windows version can be viewed here:

https://www.stunnel.org/config_windows.html

I use this to connect to a Redis cache service that is hosted on Azure, and I did so by adding a simple entry as shown below:

```
; ***************************************** Example TLS client mode services
[redis-cli]
client = yes
accept = 127.0.0.1:6380
connect = xxxxxx.redis.cache.windows.net:6380
```

The basics are straightforward; you are stating that connections are accepted to your local machine (127.0.0.1) on port 6380, and are being connected to the specified remote host and port. There is good documentation available for other scenarios.

Now, the original question does not specify what *type* of credentials you need to pass, or what the client application is. In the scenarios that I encounter, it is the client that passes the credentials to the connection, and STunnel handles the port forwarding.

Perhaps look at the authentication options for Stunnel here:

https://www.stunnel.org/auth.html

And ideally, supply some more background information.